# Make notification bar slide up from the bottom

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a small horizontal notification bar that slides up from the bottom of the page.

It comes up fine, but when you open up the page it quickly flashes, then disappears and then slides up.

How do I modify it so it doesn't appear/disappear before the transition takes place?

```css
#notificationBarBottom {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #5cb85c;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(510px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideDown {
  0%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(510px);
  }
}
.cssanimations.csstransforms #notificationBarBottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(510px);
  -webkit-animation: slideDown 2.5s 1.0s 1 ease forwards;
  -moz-transform: translateY(510px);
  -moz-animation: slideDown 2.5s 1.0s 1 ease forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="notificationBarBottom">Hello, human!</div>
```

Jsfiddle demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/cnfk36jd/ (but unfortunately the problem is not visible there). Here's the page where you can see the "flickering" http://www.whycall.me/bannerTest.html

I tried the advice here: https://css-tricks.com/pop-from-top-notification/ and tweaked the translateY values quite a bit, but it doesn't help, not sure what else to do.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please try with the following: (make iterations value 0)::

.cssanimations.csstransforms #notificationBarBottom {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(510px);
    -webkit-animation: slideDown 2.5s 1.0s 0 ease forwards;
    -moz-transform:    translateY(510px);
    -moz-animation:    slideDown 2.5s 1.0s 0 ease forwards;
}

Comment: it didn't work, it only removed the smooth transition from the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements initial position is visible, and then, during page load, the first translate kicks in to hide it, hence it flickers.

Do like this, push it out of view using `transform: translateY(calc(100% + 10px));` and then slide it up with `transform: translateY(0));`.

*I used `100%` instead of `-510px` to make it height independent, and added `10px` to make up for the top shadow.*

*I also temporary removed the prefixed properties, so you need to add them back*

***Updated 2021:*** *Updated answer, improved the code suggestion, and, based on a comment, added how to make it hide using a click*

```js
document.getElementById('notificationBarBottom').addEventListener('click', function() {
   this.classList.add('hideMe');
})
```

```css
#notificationBarBottom {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(calc(100% + 10px));
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #5cb85c;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.5;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
@keyframes slideUp {
    0% { transform: translateY(100% + 10px); }
    100% { transform: translateY(0); }
}
#notificationBarBottom {
    animation: slideUp 2.5s ease forwards;
}
#close {
  display: none;
}

/* added to show how to hide with a click */
@keyframes slideDown {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(100% + 10px); }
}
#notificationBarBottom.hideMe {
    animation: slideDown 2.5s ease forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="notificationBarBottom">Hello, human!</div>
```

Comment: I like this answer, but without an explanation i cant upvote this.

Comment: @Persijn Added one

Comment: Sure have my upvote, but you are just saying what you are doing. Not why his is flickering, and yours is not.

Comment: @Persijn Updated ... :)

Comment: works great! so the solution was to remove one of the translates, correct? thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: can you please add a  semicolon  after color: #ffffff , my OCD's acting up:)

Comment: @RobertSinclair Updated with a `;` ... :) ... and the major of the solution was to remove 1 translate and re-position the notification bar

Comment: How can you change it so that you can click on the div and make the message disappear?

Comment: @D.Man -- Improved my answer and added how to hide with a click.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because the css file in which you've written this code is called a bit too late.

In your html page, try calling this css file earlier than other css or JS files